For a massive hydrobattery building, what scales could be feasible at all?
Say 0.5-7 million cubic metres of a liquid 2.5x denser than water. What types of shapes, heights, materials could even be explored for a hydrobattery building of this scale?

what do you mean by types of shapes?

Do you mean to ask what structural materials could contain it rather than letting it spread it over the ~500 trillion square meter planet surface? If you're concerned about cost of  structure, build it underground.

I think you will struggle to find a liquid with the density you describe.

Consider a liquid 13.5 times denser than water - this would reduce the volumes needed. Or a limestone or sand slurry, but keeping the slurry homogenous may be an issue depending on settling.

Lakes do this quite well.
